# SQL Duplicated Rows by Three Columns Only

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, having-clause

I am trying to extract records only if the content of fields prl.attribute1, a.owner_role, and b.responder are the same.  I am using a group by and the count function, but it does not work.  What am I doing wrong?  Here goes my code.

```
select
b.notification_id,
b.item_key,
b.begin_date,
b.end_date,
replace(b.subject,'"','') as subject,
a.owner_role as initiator,
b.responder as approver,
b.RECIPIENT_ROLE,
b.from_role,
prl.attribute1 reg_num,
c.proxy_role As Responder,
c.action,
sum(case prl.line_type_id
         when 1 then -- goods 
            round(nvl(prl.rate,1) * prl.quantity * prl.unit_price,0)
         when 1020 then -- rate based 
            round(nvl(prl.rate,1) * prl.quantity * prl.unit_price,0)
         when 1024 then -- rate based 
            round(nvl(prl.rate,1) * prl.quantity * prl.unit_price,0)
         when 1025 then
            round(nvl(prl.rate,1) * prl.quantity * prl.unit_price,0)
         when 1021 then -- amount based service 
            round(nvl(prl.currency_amount,prl.amount) * nvl(prl.rate,1),0)
         when 1022 then -- insurance 
            round(nvl(prl.currency_amount,prl.amount) * nvl(prl.rate,1),0)
         when 1023 then -- pf 
            round(nvl(prl.currency_amount,prl.amount) * nvl(prl.rate,1),0)
      end
   ) req_amount_us
from
apps.po_requisition_lines_all prl
Left join
apps.po_requisition_headers_all prh On  prl.requisition_header_id=prh.requisition_header_id
Left Join
wf_items a On prh.requisition_header_id=to_number(substr(a.item_key,1,instr(a.item_key,'-',1)-1))
Left Join
wf_notifications b On substr(a.item_key,1,instr(a.item_key,'-',1))=substr(b.item_key,1,instr(b.item_key,'-',1))
Left Join
wf_comments c On b.notification_id=c.notification_id AND c.action ='RESPOND_WA'
Where 1=1
  --and prl.attribute1 = '2017/764570'
  and a.item_type = 'REQAPPRV'
  and a.root_activity= 'MAIN_REQAPPRV_PROCESS'
  and b.begin_date >= '01-JAN-2017'
  and b.message_type = 'REQAPPRV'
  and b.message_name = 'XXAPPROVAL_NOTIFICATION'
  --and b.responder = a.owner_role
group by
b.notification_id, b.begin_date, b.end_date, b.subject, b.item_key, /*a.item_key,*/ a.owner_role, b.responder,b.RECIPIENT_ROLE,  b.from_role, prl.attribute1, c.proxy_role, c.action
Having
Count(prl.attribute1) > 1
and Count (a.owner_role) > 1
and Count (b.responder) > 1
Order by prl.attribute1, b.begin_date, b.notification_id
```

Comment: try with `inner join` instead `left join`

Comment: you want the values to be the same or the count to be the same?

Comment: I want the query to extract only the lines where the prl.attribute1, a.owner_role, and b.responder.are the same.  The other fields could be different.

Comment: add this to your where clause: "prl.attribute1 = a.owner_role and a.owner_role=b.responder", see what you get back.  What about nulls, if they are all null does that count as a match?

Comment: Dazak after I use Inner join instead of left join, the query works fine in those cases where there are more than lines having the duplicated fields.  However, the query still extracts records where there is one line only.